# Pin Verification Dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am triyng to make PIN Verification dialog with PHP, BOOTSTRAP, AND AJAX. If the function returns 1 then execute the code. I tried to make two functions:
1. Open the modal dialog and get the pin.
2. Make ajax request to the server to verify the pin.
I call the first function inside the second function to get the pin.
Here is the code:

```
function PinProverka() {
    var rez;
    var pin = GetPin();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/includes/procesi.php",
            data: {
                proces: "proverka-pin",
                pin: pin
            },
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                rez = data;
            }
        });
       return rez;

}
function GetPin() {
    $("#pin-dialog").modal({backdrop: "static"}).on('click', '#pin-ok',function() {
       var pinkod = $("#pinkod").val();
       $("#pin-dialog").modal('hide');
       return pinkod;
   });

}
```

How to force the PinProverka function to wait for GetPin then executes the AJAX call and return the vaule?

Comment: jQuery's ajax function lets you define a callback function. You have one here, the `success` function, that's where you continue execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add submit or other button for handling when user entered pin.

Comment: I tried varius solutions but this is I think the best. I tried with javascript prompt and works perfectly but I need it with bootstrap modal